# How to write Hadoop Reducer's final output into a text file?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop. I was trying to modify the WordCount example to do the below task (setting the key to be second element, and the fourth and fifth elements at the correspondin value for that key, and then group them together based on the key values and writing the final results into a text file):

```
Input.txt :
a:b:c:d:e:f
g:h:i:j:k:l
m:b:n:o:p:q

Output.txt :
b:d:o:e:p
h:j:k
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Test {

    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
                String [] temp = value.toString().split(":");
                String remainder = temp[3] + ":" +temp[4];
                output.collect(new Text(temp[1]), new Text(remainder));
            }
        }


    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
            Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {

            String temp ="";
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                temp = temp + values.next().toString();     

            }

            //String remainder = ":" +temp;
            output.collect(key,new Text(temp));// point
            // :
            // distance
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Test.class);
        conf.setJobName("pivotpoints");

        System.out.println(conf.getNumMapTasks() + "map runs");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf); 
    }   
}
```

This is the output I am getting from the above code:

```
part-00000 :
b d:eo:p
h j:k
```

So, my question is :How to make Hadoop to write the final output into a text file in a given format using special separation symbol?

Comment: Set the property mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator in the configurations from your main class. 
conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator",":");

Comment: @ArunAK, Thank you so much Arun, it solved first part of my problem. Now, the output is like this:   "b:d:eo:p"   ;However, I want "b:d:e:o:p" ; in which it grouped two pairs of (key:"b" , value: "d:e" ) and (key:"b" , value: "o:p") that have the same key.

Comment: Also, how to write final output into a text file?

Comment: When you emit the key values from the Reducer, it goes to a text file by default, the part-r-00000 file.

From your map, just emit the key and value, you need not do the concatenation operation. 

That can be done at the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator in the configurations from your main class.

```
conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator",":");
```

Map to emit following sequence,

```
key value 
b d
b e
h j
h k
b o
b p
```

Reducer will automatically get it grouped as

```
b [d, e, o, p]
h [j, k]
```

You can iterate over the list of values for each key in the reducer and put your : between the values, concatenate them to a single string.

Reducer can then emit

```
Key Value 
b d:e:o:p (your concatenated string)
h j:k (your concatenated string)
```

Since you have set the separator as `:` instead `tab` of the output file will have the result as expected.

Comment: Thank you, I made it work! :)
I have the output in the part-00000 file. How should I make hadoop to write the output in a text file? Is it possible? or I should just copy the output file from dfs to a text file in my local disk?

Comment: The part -r file by itself is a text file. You can use it and perform any operation that you do on normal text file. Only change is that it does not come with the .txt extension. You can always copy/move/rename the file as per your requirement.